# Facebook friends suddenly showing up in Outlook People

Tags: outlook.com, contacts, microsoft-account

Ever since Facebook changed their API a couple of years ago, Facebook friends no longer sync with third party apps/services. Since then, Facebook friends stopped appearing in the Outlook.com People/contacts page. However, suddenly on my Android phone, all the Facebook friends I had back then (some of which are now unfriended) are now showing up in the Contacts app (along with lots of `(no name)`s for some reason). I traced this to my Microsoft account contacts. I logged in to Outlook People and they're showing up there too (but not in the Windows 10 People app). I think they must have changed something back-end recently.

**I want to remove my Facebook friends from my Microsoft account contacts.** I've tried disconnecting Facebook from my account following the most helpful answer at [this answers.microsoft post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/opeople-ocontacts/how-can-i-remove-all-facebook-contacts-from-my/75e149a7-7669-46a8-9f53-78abdb132c4a) but it hasn't worked. Bearing in mind that post is a few years old. I can't delete the contacts individually from Outlook.com People.

Comment: Are you seeing same on browser also?

Comment: @serenesat I'm seeing Facebook friends in the browser on Outlook.com People